# ANTLRworks and Java grammar problems

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr3, antlrworks, antlr4

I'm working through a ANTLR  to generate AST for Java code using Java grammar and i used the command line  to compile the files, and i got these problems:

when I used the antlrworks-1-1.4.3.jar with this [Java.g](http://www.habelitz.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=8), and when compiling the files with javac, I  got 1 error , which is

```
JavaParser.java:24631: illegal start of expression
        void  =null;
        ^ 1 error
```

I have tried using antlrworks-1.5.jar and  antlr-1.3.jar, and in both I got 100 errors

I'm using mac 10.6.8 and Java 1.6_37. Can please someone tell How I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was resolved in the ANTLR 3.5 release (included with ANTLRWorks 1.5). ANTLRWorks 1.5 has a [separate bug which has since been fixed](https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/issues/5) that will cause compiler errors if you try to generate grammars with the `-debug` flag, but should work fine for normal use.